# How can I remove the little black line next to the Instagram logo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[this is how it shows up on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIjk1.png)

[this is the code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1emUl.png)

I don't see where my issue is and what is generating the little black "-" line next to the Instagram icon logo.

Comment: share your code as text and not as a picture

Comment: <a href="#instagram">
<img alt="Qries" src="insta.png" style="width:10%">
</a>
<a href="#facebook">
<img alt="Qries" src="fb.png" style="width:10%">
</a>

Comment: @Alice Bittar Welcome to SO. You should use SO internal code snippet tool add your code. And if you have local images use codepen.io and share you link here. That way we can debug it better. The code in the image shared looks fine

Comment: `text-decoration:none;` on href

Comment: Assuming the line isn't in the image itself, please put your code into a Stackoverflow snippet - enough of your HTML and CSS that it shows the problem (and include uploads of your images).

Answer (score 2):

You can point your mouse to the black line and right-click > inspect. That way you can find which part of the code is producing the line. However if you are unable to find the element that is causing the line, it may be because of the image itself or some rendering issue

Comment: I just tried changing the image to see if that would fix the issue and its still there

Comment: Also I looked into the inspection of the page and it links the issue area within the <a></a> hyperlink tag, but cant find any thing

Answer (score 1):

As Much I could understand, You are a beginner. So, Start asking question is ways as suggested in comments.

You want to remove the black "-" dash, You are seeing this, because  is a link item, we no text, it is showing link.
Before and after the img there is whitespace within the a. If a elements are styled to be underlined, that whitespace will be underlined.
To remove that, use text-decoration and set it to none

```css
a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/lindaazab" id="instaIcon">
 <img alt="Qries" src="https://webstockreview.net/images/instagram-clipart-transparent-background.png" style="width: 10%;" /> 
</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/horses.linda" id="fbIcon">
  <img alt="Qries" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/facebook-logo-11549681668z1ra1h6mmx.png" style="width: 10%;"/>
</a>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5k2qhjea/), If you want to play more.

Comment: I actually want to remove the little "-" from being next to the clickable insta icon on my page. It appeared once I added the another clickable facebooka icon next to it.

Comment: [Alyce Bittar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15209007/alyce-bittar) I have updated the answer, Run it again.

Comment: perfect thank you!! the CSS code fixed it, it was the text-decoration code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a text shadow the color of the background. If it does not work then the problem is with the image.